# INNER JOIN vs MultiSelect in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, inner-join

Can somebody completely explain what is big difference in these two methods?
Is there misunderstanding in database theory of programmers? Can somebody give a good article about the question or just say - what is a difference in these methods in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see the difference. PostgreSQL is pretty smart in executing queries, it might come up with the same queryplan for both types of queries.

Comment: By `multiselect` you perhaps mean `subselect`?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/sql-join-vs-subquery

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean SELECT * FROM table1, table2 vs SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON condition?

PostgreSQL optimizer makes this queries run with the same speed, but JOIN is more transparent and usable. Also, you can use LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: The first version is also subject to accidental cross joins and the second is much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

In the PostgreSQL documentation there is a related topic. Explicit joins can give you more control over the execution order of statements using the join_collapse_limit GUC. Take a look at [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/explicit-joins.html).

There are also all the other already mentioned advantages in readability and maintainability.